# Current Shia sect that rejects Uthman's edit of the Quran

Tags: quran, shiism, rashidi-caliphs

I understand that in Shia Islam the first three Rashidun are grasped as unlawful political successors of Muhammad in leading the Ummah and in any case unfit to lead justly by their verity to replace Ali as caliph.

I have read in the past that some "Shia" scholars alleged the Quran as not entirely divine due to Uthman's edits but this paradigm came up from  individual "Shia" persons, not from any of the current Shia sect.

Is there a current Shia sect that rejects Uthman's edit of the Quran so to accept only some part of the Quran or to use an edited Quran of their own?

Answer (score 1):

I know about the Shiites of 12 Imams who believe that the Qur'an is without distortion. And for them, the Qur'an of Uthman Taha, like any other Qur'an, can be read and referred to. The Shiites, citing Sura 15: 9, believe that what we have from the Qur'an is the true and complete Qur'an, and there has been no distortion in the Qur'an throughout history.

Many great Shiite scholars, authorities and thinkers have written books about rejecting the distortion of the Qur'an and tried to prove with various rational and narrative arguments that the Qur'an is available to Muslims without distortion and more or less.

https://fa.wikifeqh.ir/%D8%B9%D8%AF%D9%85_%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%81_%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A2%D9%86_(%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AF%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87_%D8%B4%DB%8C%D8%B9%D9%87)#foot-main5